# Query annotation is disallowed for this location

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

New to Spring ..

Trying to use the @Query annotation but get a message of:
The annotation @Query is disallowed for this location

Got to be some setup or configuration I am missing here is what I have:

pom.xml

```
<parent>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
 <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
 <relativePath/>
</parent>
… to dependency:
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>      
</dependency>
```

Compelled to use 1.5.2.RELEASE as it is the employer's current standard
Looking in the Maven dependences I see:
hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar
+ many others

in some of the examples I have seen it seems like a easy matter to add the @Query annotation however it does not seem to work. currently I have just a entity, repo, controller and a main.

I have tried the @Repository but it does not seem to make a difference

here's the repo

```
public interface DeptRepo extends JpaRepository<Dept, Long> {

@Query(value = "select d from dept d where name = 'ACCOUNTING'")
List<Dept> findByAccounting;
}
```

application properties

```
spring.jpa.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/to2b
spring.datasource.username=scott
spring.datasource.password=tiger
```

My question is what is the setup info I am missing?

Comment: findByAccounting should be a function. And also which `@Query` are you using. can you put the imported package details

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
public interface DeptRepo extends JpaRepository<Dept, Long> {
   @Query(value = "select d from dept d where name = 'ACCOUNTING'")
   List<Dept> findByAccounting;
}
```

Use

```
public interface DeptRepo extends JpaRepository<Dept, Long> {
  @Query(value = "select d from dept d where name = 'ACCOUNTING'")
  List<Dept> findByAccounting(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get a compilation error as the one you mentioned, namely:

> The annotation `@Query` is disallowed for this location

Then it means that you're using an annotation somewhere it's not meant for. If an annotation only allows you to put it on top of a method, you'll get this exception when you put it on top of your class, or on top of a property.

In this case, the `@Query` annotation is only targets methods and other annotations (so that you can use it to form custom annotations), as seen in the [API documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html):

> ```
> @Target(value={METHOD,ANNOTATION_TYPE})
> ```

You should define your queries as **methods**, currently you mapped it to a field. To solve it, write a method:

```
@Query(value = "select d from dept d where name = 'ACCOUNTING'")
List<Dept> findByAccounting(); // Using "()"
```

Answer (score 0):

is your repository package mapped to the configuration class?

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
        "br.com.example.repository"}, entityManagerFactoryRef = "exampleEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "exampleTransactionManager")
public class ExampleDataSourceConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "exampleEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean exampleEntityManager() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(exampleDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { 
                "br.com.example.domain"});

        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        final HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");      
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("examplePU");
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        return em;
    }

    public DataSource exampleDataSource() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        DataSource dataSource = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/examplejndi");
        return dataSource;

    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "exampleTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager exampleTransactionManager() {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(exampleEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }   
}
```